MobaXTerm X11 works but says it doesn't, and it also doesn't work
MobaXerm says X11 is disabled, but the X server is running and here in this pic I have launched the geany text editor. This is at home on win10 on the same network as the linux server. So X11 forwarding is working.
When I connect from work X11 forwarding does not work. It used to work fine before a recent update on Ubuntu where I elected to keep the existing configs. That was some time ago, weeks, as I seldom log in from work so I didn't notice. Work is using win11 pc's
Any ideas what is happening?
EDIT: I dug into my .bashrc as I remember I have a line I added in there
export DISPLAY="192.168.2.22:0.0"
which is why it works on my home desktop PC, why does it now need thsi added to work?  What changed recently in ubuntu X11


Can you expand some on the second paragraph? What do you mean when you say "when I connect from WORK..."? Is this over a VPN? Is this from a different computer ?Do you own the computer? Are there business firewall or application policies at work here? Please note that as this problem is happening on your work computer, it is likely this question will be closed, because we cannot know what all policies are enforced on your work computer, and we will not assist in circumventing any controls placed by the owner of the system.

I am not trying to circumvent work firewalls. I connect via port 22, all working fine, but X11 (as in the picture) is disabled yet also enabled which makes no sense.  This started at the same time it started on my home network.  I own the server I am connecting to, I do not own the work laptop. I am connecting from my work laptop via the office network adn internet, no VPN.  Error is cannot open display for any application I try to launch.
